# Algorithm to find all linearly separable bipartitions

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given a set $S$ of $N$ points in $d$-dimensional euclidean space.
I know that the number of different ways to separate these points in exactly two
disjoint subsets by an hyperplane is limited by $2\sum^d_{k=0} \binom{N-1}{k}$, which is polynomial in $N$.

QUESTION: Does anyone know if there exist an algorithm to find all possible subsets of $S$ which can be separated by an hyperplane?

Comment: Looking online I could only find literature which considers *optimal* linear bipartitions (searching for the best according to some criterion) and only in two-dimensions. Yes, for fixed dimension $d$ the number of bipartitions is polynomially bounded (in $N$), but it is unclear if you will be happy e.g. with an algorithm that provides these with possible repetitions, etc.  What does "efficient" require in this context?

Comment: Yes, finding one optimal linear bipartition (w.r.t. some criterion) is a well known optimization problem. I'am happy with any algorithm (even with possible repetitions) or even a link to similar problem in another field (e.g. graph theory) might be helpful. I expect that there exists a polynomial time algorithm for fixed dimension $d$, since the number of possible linear bipartitions is polynomially bounded in $N$.

Comment: A starting point is finding all the singleton sets that can be so separated, i.e. [Enumerating Extreme Points in Higher
Dimensions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.33.8834&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  This 1995 paper by Ottmann et al also explores the [convex layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers) problem (partitioning a finite set into "nested" convex hulls).  My thought is that this will be an ingredient to solving your higher dimensional problem.